# Change the switch code

Tags: javascript, jquery, require.js

there is a other way to write in JS the switch statement ,
This code is working :)

```
_update: function(oHtml, oConfig) {
        var _this = this;
        var oParent;
        if (oConfig.attributes != null) {
            oConfig.attributes.forEach(function(oAttr) {
                //debugger;
                oParent = oHtml.find("#" + oAttr.id);
                switch (oAttr.action) {
                    case 'upd':
                        _this._updateAttr(oParent, oAttr);
                        break;
                    case 'new':
                        _this._insertAttr(oParent, oAttr);
                        break;
                    case 'del':
                        _this._removeAttr(oParent, oAttr);
                }
            });
            return oHtml;
        }
    },
```

We are using require JS

Comment: I can think of multiple ways to write that, yes. Your point?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is working code.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer - why can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Do you want to avoid the switch statement?

Comment: @KimAragonEscobar - yes if there is nicer way in JS maybe with mapReduce

Comment: Please tell us what this code is for, and title the question accordingly. See [ask].

Comment: @NinaS https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/126012/revisions was updated ~15 mins after I made the comment and just around the time you asked elaboration. So technically "This code is working" isn't true before that edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this, saving the names of the functions in a variable, and then accessing the variable with the name of the action, you can also save the reference of the functions of the variable in the properties and you would not have to use 'this'

```
_update: function(oHtml, oConfig) {
    var _this = this;
    var oParent;
    var actionsToExecute = {
      upd : '_updateAttr',
      new : '_insertAttr',
      del : '_removeAttr'
    }
    if (oConfig.attributes != null) {
        oConfig.attributes.forEach(function(oAttr) {
            //debugger;
            oParent = oHtml.find("#" + oAttr.id);
            _this[actionsToExecute[oAttr.action]](oParent,oAttr)
        });
        return oHtml;
    }
},
```

Comment: Would be even better if you could change the value of oAttr.action to return one of the 3 function name because you wouldn't need the 'actionsToExecute' object.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I made a clarification in the end.